# LXD: LXC Network Edit Results in Error: Not Found

Tags: ubuntu, networking, containers, lxc, lxd

I want a predictable network bridge to use with LXD so that I can run squid as a proxy on that bridge for all traffic and add ebtables rules for filtering traffic.

So I edited /etc/network/interfaces to add the bridge:

```
auto cdplxdbr0
iface cdplxdbr0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 127.0.0.1
    bridge_ports enp0s10f1

#auto enp0s10f1
iface enp0s10f1 inet manual
```

On reboot, the interface comes up correctly as can be seen by

```
cdplxdbr0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5d:7a:3f:01
      inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::215:5dff:fe7a:3f01/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1042261 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:103937980 (103.9 MB)  TX bytes:738 (738.0 B)

enp0s10f0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5d:7a:3f:00
      inet addr:10.91.128.126  Bcast:10.91.131.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::215:5dff:fe7a:3f00/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:445061 errors:0 dropped:417 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:11474 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:91505926 (91.5 MB)  TX bytes:2185293 (2.1 MB)

enp0s10f1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5d:7a:3f:01
      inet addr:10.91.130.127  Bcast:10.91.131.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1541116 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:990 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:237056633 (237.0 MB)  TX bytes:43292 (43.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:5921 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:5921 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
      RX bytes:490582 (490.5 KB)  TX bytes:490582 (490.5 KB)
```

Next, I added the device eth0 to the default LXD profile and this also shows up correctly:

```
$ lxc profile show default
name: default
config: {}
description: Default LXD profile
devices:
    eth0:
        name: eth0
        nictype: bridged
        parent: cdplxdbr0
        type: nic
    usedby: []
```

When inspecting the configuration:

```
$ lxc network show cdplxdbr0
name: cdplxdbr0
config: {}
managed: false
type: bridge
usedby: []
```

I want the device to be assigned a static IP address and a use NAT for IPv4, so I did something like this:

```
$ cat /cdp/endor/scripts/lxd/lxdbr1.yml  | lxc network edit cdplxdbr0
error: not found
```

Where the contents of lxdbr1.yml are:

```
name: cdplxdbr0
config:
    ipv4.address: 192.168.1.1/24
    ipv4.nat: true
    ipv6.address: none
managed: false
type: bridge
```

I am not sure what's wrong with this configuration. It appears to be right w.r.t what LXD itself does when using the default configured bridge.

Answer (score 0):

In your setup, your cdplxdbr0 bridged is defined at the system level to bridge with a physical network.

In that mode, all that LXD support is attaching your containers to it as it's assuming that there is an existing gateway on that network and that it shouldn't be taking it over.

To assign static DHCP leases you should therefore configure them on whatever device operates your physical network rather than through LXD.

Or you can configure the containers not to use DHCP and use a static network configuration instead. Either configured manually in the container (/etc/network/interfaces for Ubuntu or Debian containers) or if using Ubuntu 16.04 or higher in the container, through cloud-init by setting user.network-config to a valid cloud-init network v1 config yaml.

http://curtin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/networking.html documents valid inputs for the user.network-config key.